# How to change an integer to its equivalent string in awk?

Tags: bash, unix, awk

Let's say I have a text file that has an input of 1,2,3 etc. How do I change it to one, two, three and vice versa?

I just want to know the way to set the value of the field for the if statement.

```
#! usr/bin/awk -f`
{
for(i=0; i<= NF; i++)
   if(i == "1")
     printf "one"
}
```

Comment: How high do you plan to go? 9? 99?...

Comment: I'm only going to 9.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Explanation of the code below:
The BEGIN piece of the code sets the field separator as ",". That way the for statement will loop through the fields using the $NF variable that stores the number of fields that the current record has.

The rest of the code is pretty similar to any structural programming language.

```
BEGIN { FS="," }

function get_text_number(num) {
    if(num == "0") {
        return "zero"
    }
    else if(num == "1") {
        return "one"
    }
    else if(num == "2") {
        return "two"
    }
    else if(num == "3") {
        return "three"
    }
    else if(num == "4") {
        return "four"
    }
    else if(num == "5") {
        return "five"
    }
    else if(num == "6") {
        return "six"
    }
    else if(num == "7") {
        return "seven"
    }
    else if(num == "8") {
        return "eight"
    }
    else if(num == "9") {
        return "nine"
    }
}

{
    for(i = 1; i <= NF -1 ; i++) { 
        printf("%s,",get_text_number($i)); 
    }
    printf("%s\n",get_text_number($NF)); 
}
```

Execute: `awk -f transform.awk test.txt`

Comment: Don't do that, it's a lot of duplicated code and very inefficient. Just use a mapping array.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a bunch of if-else's as that's very inefficient, hard to maintain, and susceptible to coding errors given all of the duplicate code. Just use an array (which is a very efficient hash table in awk) to map each number to it's name:

```
echo '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9' |
awk -F, 'BEGIN{split("one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine",m)}
         {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s=%s%s", $i, m[$i], (i<NF?OFS:ORS)}'
1=one 2=two 3=three 4=four 5=five 6=six 7=seven 8=eight 9=nine
```